# Как сменить каталог templates в Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Операционка Windows. В приложении структура каталогов:

```yaml
java
├─ resources
│  └─ templates
└─ webapp
   ├─ WEB-INF   
   └─ templates
```

По умолчанию Thymeleaf настроен на

```yaml
└─ resources
   └─ templates
```

Как мне сменить каталог templates в Thymeleaf на

```yaml
└─ webapp
   ├─ WEB-INF   
   └─ templates
```

Прописал настройки в пропертях:

```yaml
sping:
  thymeleaf:  
    prefix: classpath:/webapp/templates/
```

не работает, все равно пишет:

```
Cannot find template location: classpath:/webapp/templates/
```

Answer (score 1):

В настройках [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) нужно переопределить метод `configureViewResolvers`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver =
                new ServletContextTemplateResolver(servletContext);
        // Папка с шаблонами относительно папки 'webapp'.
        // Полный путь: '/src/main/webapp/view/'.
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/view/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource =
                new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        // Расположение файла 'messages.properties' с константами.
        // Полный путь: '/src/main/resources/messages.properties'.
        messageSource.setBasename("resources/messages");

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);

        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }
}
```

Метод [`viewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ViewResolverRegistry.html#viewResolver-org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver-) можно вызывать несколько раз для разных папок с шаблонами с разными настройками.